# HTML.DropDownListFor not passing parameter to controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, filter, html.dropdownlistfor

i am trying to filter my view for a couple of hours by now. This is what i have:
My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RH_CentroCusto", FormMethod.Get))
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.DepartmentoSelecionado , Model.Departamentos, "Select")
}
```

in my Model Class :

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departamentos { get; set; }
 public string DepartmentoSelecionado { get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
//i want to receive the value in departamentoSelecionado !!
 public IActionResult Index( string searchString, string departamentoSelecionado = "", int page = 1)
     
     
            List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (var x in _context.RH_Departamento.ToList())
            {
                selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Departamento , Value = x.Departamento           });
            }

//and then i add to the viewModel that i create the list
        ViewModelCentroCusto vmcc = new ViewModelCentroCusto()
            {  
                   Departamentos = selectList
            }
```

When i try to select one and click enter, it is suposed to be passing because in my browser i inspected and it was passing query parameters:

[image]

But in my controller my departamentoSelecionado  is null, also the dropdown list gets the "select" again instead of keeping what i choose before! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `departamentoSelecionado`  to `departmentoSelecionado` . You spelt an extra letter **a** in `departmentoSelecionado` .

```
//public IActionResult Index( string searchString, string departamentoSelecionado = "", int page = 1)
  public IActionResult Index( string searchString, string departmentoSelecionado = "", int page = 1)
```

The parameter in action method should be same as `f => f.DepartmentoSelecionado`.

### Update 16/09/2020

Codes of controller

```
public class RH_CentroCustoController : Controller
{
   
    //i want to receive the value in departamentoSelecionado !!
    public IActionResult Index(string searchString, string departmentoSelecionado ="", int page = 1)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        IList<RH_Departamento> RH_Departamento = new List<RH_Departamento>(){
            new RH_Departamento(){ Departamento="dep1" },
            new RH_Departamento(){ Departamento="dep2" },
            new RH_Departamento(){ Departamento="dep3" },
        };//just for test 
        //foreach (var x in _context.RH_Departamento.ToList())
        foreach (var x in RH_Departamento.ToList())
        {
            selectList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Departamento, Value = x.Departamento });
        }

        //and then i add to the viewModel that i create the list
        ViewModelCentroCusto vmcc = new ViewModelCentroCusto()
        {
            Departamentos = selectList
        };

        return View(vmcc);
    }
}
```

Codes of View

```
@model xxx.Models.ViewModelCentroCusto
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "RH_CentroCusto", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.DepartmentoSelecionado, new SelectList(Model.Departamentos, "Value", "Text"), "Select");
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Codes of Model

```
public class ViewModelCentroCusto
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departamentos { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentoSelecionado { get; set; }
}

public class RH_Departamento
{
    public string Departamento { get; set; }
}
```

### Test

[image]

Comment: Omg, i dont know how i missed that! xD  Thanks for the help and i am sorry but i had no notification... :/ Really appreciated! thanks! :D

Comment: By the way, this code works but when i select my choice i want it to submit the form right away!  Right now that does not happen! I am new to asp.net and i still didn´t read anything about that, but if you land me some information i would be appreciated! :)

Comment: There are some errors existed in your code. And will update the codes above.

Comment: Isn´t your code equal to mine?  i am not getting any errors and i am not able to see any difference in your code and mine! :/ 

By the way, can you do that, but instead of using a button, instantly submit when choosen ? so that if i choose one it will filter right away!?

Thanks for this huge help you are giving mate! :)

Comment: try this `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DepartmentoSelecionado, new SelectList(Model.Departamentos, "Value", "Text"), "Select", new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" });`